# how to downscale 4k with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, 4k

I have been searching all the web on how to downscale 4k video so that it can play on my non 4k TV.

My 4k video has a resolution of 3840 x 2160 with an audio format of pcm_s16be in a mp4 container. I am trying to convert it to 1920 x 1080 with an audio format of aac.
I use Lubuntu and have been experimenting with the command lines without success.

Thanks

Update -- After further searching I found this code which converts the audio from pcw to aac

ffmpeg -y -i C0010.MP4 -vcodec copy -strict experimental  -c:a aac output-fileC0010.MP4

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: I have lost track of the number of commands I have tried but here is an example - ffmpeg -i output-file.MP4-vf scale=iw/2:-1 outputt.mp4

Comment: Assuming the lack of space between `MP4` and `-vf` is a typo, command looks ok. What's the issue?

Comment: Ah, but I still have not managed to write the command to downscale the video after encoding the audio ...